# Deck transformation of the $n$-sheeted covering $\Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

From Hatcher:

> For the $n$-sheeted covering space $S^1\to S^1$, $z\mapsto z^n$, the deck tranformations are the rotations of $S^1$ through angles that are multiples of $2\pi/n$.

Why is this so? I don't really understand it.

I can understand the analogous result for $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$, $G(\widetilde{X})=\mathbb{Z}$, since the deck transformations are vertical translations.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the same approach that works for the covering $\Bbb R \to \Bbb S^1$.

By definition, a deck transformation $\phi : \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb S^1$ must preserve the covering map $\pi : z \mapsto z^n$, that is $\pi = \pi \circ \phi$. Substituting gives $$z^n = \phi(z)^n ,$$ and rearranging gives $(z^{-1} \phi(z))^n = 1$, and hence for all $n$ $$\phi(z) = e^{2 \pi i k / n} z$$ for some integer $k$. Since (again by definition) $\phi$ is continuous, $k$ must be the same for all $z$. But these are precisely the rotations of $\Bbb S^1$ by multiples $\frac{2 \pi k}{n}$ of $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Travis' nice answer (+1), you can also note that firstly all rotations by multiples of $2\pi/n$ are Deck transformations, and that secondly they together act transitively on each fiber. Since a Deck transformation is determined by its action on a single point, it follows that they are already all.